# PHP PDO ALlowed Memory Exhausted when allocating 64 bytes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 scripts which are technically the same, but one works, and the other produces the error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\SOTag\SOTag.php on line 29
```

Line 29 being:

```
$rows[] = $r;
```

**This is the code that works:**

```
$this->connect_db();
$statement = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE :keywords");
$statement->bindParam(':keywords', $keywords, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute(compact('keywords'));

$rows = array();
while($r = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
return json_encode($rows);
```

**And this is what I need to do (as I need to check for results) but it fails:**

```
$this->connect_db();
$statement = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE :keywords");
$statement->bindParam(':keywords', $keywords, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute(compact('keywords'));
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$rows = array();
while($r = $result) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
return json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: why are you using `while($r = while($r = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {` ?

Comment: Sorry thats a mistake, I'll edit

Comment: Are you sure your first snippet works?

Comment: How many rows are being returned? What's the memory limit on your PHP install? I have a feeling you're returning too much data to hold in the amount of memory allowed

Comment: @RandomSeed you know, it is not a duplicate

Comment: There is 1 row being returned, this is a tiny script, it's just running on my local machine on localhost with the standard settings

Comment: @YourCommonSense Fair enough. The OP having not demonstrated any debugging attempt, I didn't read further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

too much errors in your code, it's easier to rewrite it:

```
$statement = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE ?");
$statement->execute(array($keywords));
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
return json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've created an infinite loop:

```
$rows = array();
while($r = $result) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```

PHP is just preventing you from crashing the whole server.

Comment: This answer saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`while($r = $result) {` is the problem.

`$result` is always evaluated as true, so the loop never stop.

You have to do this:

```
while($r = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: Ok, so I suppose I need to ask, how do I check for results without executing the query twice?

Comment: @Adam Why will the query be executed twice? `fetch` does not execute query.

Comment: Oh sorry I was under the assumption it did